# get ajax select option value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I Have Two Dropdown State And Zipcode , When User Click On State , Zip code Loaded from Ajax . In Zip code I have Set The Function of change to get Value of zip code select option. But jquery Giving me undefined Value . Here is Complete Code.How Can I Get The Zip Code Value

```
    <select name="sState" id="sState" onChange="LoadZipCode();">
          <?php $resultState=$objGeneral->GetStates();
    echo '<option value="default">select The States</option>';
    while($rowState=$resultState->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    { 
    echo '<option value="'.$rowState[2].'">'.$rowState[1].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<select data-live-search="true" class="form-control selectpicker" name="sZip" id="sZip" onChange="LoadCity();" required>
</select>
```

In Jquery  Here Script For  Loading Zip Code

```
   <script>
function LoadZipCode()
{
var StateAbbre=$("#sState").val();  
$.post("DashboardProcess.php?action=getZipCode",{StateAbbr:StateAbbre},function(data)
{
$("#sZip").html(data);
$('#sZip').selectpicker('refresh'); 
});
}
</script>
<script>
function LoadCity()
{
alert($(this).find('#zipCode option').val());   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the name attribute from the Select element. IN console(F12) try $("#sState").val(), to check what it is giving.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about undefined value? your js code looks perfect to me. which variable is giving undefined value?